# how to remove a range of elements from an array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I need to remove a range of elements from an array but I can't figure out how. 
I tried this for loop where start is that start of the range and end is the end of the range.

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
a1[start+i] = a1[end+i+1];;
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Please add what happens with what you tried. If possible please give actual and expected output.

Comment: Check your for condition, i think you should try i<n-end.

Comment: @p.martin can you provide an example input and output, also can you post ur whole code here. It will be easy for us then

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

> to remove a range of elements from an array

In C, once an *array* is defined, the range of elements is fixed.  They cannot be *removed*. [@hyde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318956/how-to-remove-a-range-of-elements-from-an-array-in-c/52319617#comment91586282_52318956)

---

Code can at run time, re-assign element values.

With an array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and we want to "removed" `[3,4,5]` and then end up with `[1,2,6,7, x, x, x]`.  Here `x` needs to be *some value*, perhaps 0.

```
size_t start;                              // Array index of sub-range beginning to "remove"
size_t end;                                // Array index of sub-range end to "remove"
size_t n = sizeof a1/sizeof a1[0];           // Number of elements in the array
assert(start < n && end < n && start <= end);// Make certain we have sane input    

size_t n_move = end - start + 1; // Number of elements to move 
memmove(&a1[start], &a1[end + 1], sizeof a1[0]*n_move);

size_t n_clear = n - end; // Number of elements to zero 
memset(&a1[end + 1], 0, sizeof a1[0]*n_clear);
```

---

OP code is questionable as to what is `n`?
I'd expect the loop iteration count to be  `end - start + 1`.

```
sub_range_count = end - start + 1;
for (i=0; i<sub_range_count; i++){
  a1[start+i] = a1[end+i+1];;
}
```

This still leaves the later part of the array with the original values.

Comment: how can I do this without using the memmove and memset functions?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to remove a range of elements from an array but I can't figure out how. I tried this for loop where start is that start of the range and end is the end of the range.

The problem lies in your `condition` of `for` loop. It should be `length - end - 1` if you want to remove from `start` index to `end` index (including `end`). I have tried your problem and fixed it. You can try running it.

I have assumed you have been trying to move elements of `int` array.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int arrayRemove(int *array, size_t length, int start, int end)
{
    if (start >= length)
        return length;
    if (end >= length)
        return length;
    if (start > end)
        return length;

    int i;
    int toMove = length - end - 1;
    for (i = 0; i < toMove; i++)
        array[start + i] = array[end + i + 1];

    return length - end + start - 1;
}

#define SIZE    20

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int array[SIZE];
    int start = 10, end = 15;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        array[i] = i;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf("Array Element (%d): %d\r\n", i, array[i]);

    printf("---------------------\r\n");

    int finalLength = arrayRemove(array, SIZE, start, end);

    for (i = 0; i < finalLength; i++)
        printf("Array Element (%d): %d\r\n", i, array[i]);

    return 0;

}
```

---

Although `C Standard Library` `string.h` has predefined functions for moving and setting array. You can also use them since they are well tested.

The functions are [memmove](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) and [memset](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html). However, these functions takes length in terms of number of bytes to move or set. You need to use of `sizeof` operator to calculate number of bytes to move particular number of elements.

Comment: when I try to use this function I get a segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

Comment: What parameters have you passed to this function?