# removing a range of elements from an array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I need to remove a range of elements from an array but I can't figure out how. I tried this for loop where start is the start of the range and end is the end of the range.

```
int main(void)
{
int n, n2, i, start, end, index;
int a1[n];
int a2[n2];

printf("Enter the length of the array#1: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

printf("Enter the elements of the array#1: ");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
scanf("%d", &a1[i]);}

printf("Enter the length of the array#2: ");
scanf("%d", &n2);

printf("Enter the elements of the array#2: ");
for (i = 0; i < n2; i++){
scanf("%d", &a2[i]);}

printf("Enter the start and end indexof array #1 to be removed: ");
scanf("%d %d", &start, &end);

int a3[(end-start)+1];

printf("Enter the position(index)of the array #2 to be added before: ");
scanf("%d", &index);

for (i=0;i < (n - end - 1);i++){
a1[start + i] = a1[end + i + 1];
a1[end + i + 1] = 0;
}
printf("\n");
printf("array1: ");


for (i=0;i < (n);i++){
printf("%d", a1[i]);
printf(" ");
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize `n` and `n2` before using them for size of array.

Comment: This code is like `int n; printf("%d\n", n); n = 42;`. You're using `n` before giving it a value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove a range of elements from an array in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318956/how-to-remove-a-range-of-elements-from-an-array-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You have:

- Used `n` and `n2` to give size of the array without initializing those variables first. Though you have not initialized your array but if you did, it would've failed due to VLA.
- Not checked the input you are receiving from the user whether the range provided is feasible? What if `end - start` is greater than the length of the arrays.
- Used `0` as a value to replace after that element has moved to a new location/index, what if the number being moved is **0** itself?

For the last point, use some value which has a very less probability of being entered by user like `INT_MAX` & you'll be needing `limits.h` header + after that it'll be good to make your for loop look like this:

```
for(index=0;((index<sizeArr)&&((arr[index]!=INT_MAX)));++index)
```

This loop will print `start - end` lesser values from the original array.

Comment: Dear downvoter, please show some courage and point out the flaw.

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to determine the array size at runtime (via input from the user), you should be using dynamic allocation.

I'm not positive exactly what you are trying to accomplish with this script, but here's an example of what moving to dynamic allocation would look like:

```
int main(void)
{
    int n, n2, i, start, end, index;
    int *a1;
    int *a2;

    printf("Enter the length of the array#1: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    a1 = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

    printf("Enter the elements of the array#1: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    scanf("%d", &a1[i]);
    }

    printf("Enter the length of the array#2: ");
    scanf("%d", &n2);
    a2 = malloc(sizeof(int)*n2);

    printf("Enter the elements of the array#2: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n2; i++){
    scanf("%d", &a2[i]);
    }
```

You can access the values pointed to by a1 using normal array notation, but you should add some bounds checking to ensure the user does not specify an array index outside the bounds of n/n2.

Comment: Whether you use dynamic allocation or not, you still need to check the **return** of `scanf` to make sure you are processing valid data.

Comment: Using a VLA (variable length array) is also an option, but needs to be done more carefully than the code in the question. Arguably, you should check the numbers the user enters and that the memory allocations succeed.